# How to read Enobio8 device EGG signal via MNE-Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mne-python

I am currently working in a BCI project. We read the data from an Enobio8 device and when we recorded the file. The file is saved as an `.easy` format along with a `.info` file.

Below are examples of what each file contains.

1- EEG signals `.easy` file

```
-15741228   -38278653   -43620943   -6264171    -44769152   -32021816   -25153528   -4458642    0   1493932796323
-15739445   -38261326   -43603023   -6262245    -44751514   -32002525   -25150617   -4457181    0   1493932796325
-15735628   -38237066   -43565152   -6257521    -44719030   -31970720   -25144247   -4451606    0   1493932796327
-15745130   -38237608   -43547282   -6270067    -44708552   -31961981   -25153234   -4460206    0   1493932796329
-15750753   -38249011   -43547666   -6279803    -44713654   -31969142   -25159098   -4463804    0   1493932796331
-15753734   -38267076   -43566757   -6282550    -44733603   -31991900   -25162964   -4465650    0   1493932796333
-15748048   -38280731   -43597786   -6275811    -44755643   -32017350   -25157597   -4460308    0   1493932796335
```

2- EEG information `.info` file

```
StartDate (first EEG timestamp): 1493932796309
Device class: Enobio8
Device MAC: 00:0X:XX:XX:XX:XX
NIC version: v1.4.10
Operative system: Windows 8
Firmware version: 1256
Line filter status: 50 Hz
Additional channel status: OFF
EOG correction status: OFF

Total number of channels: 8
Number of EEG channels: 8
Number of records of EEG: 21839
Number of packets lost: 0(0.00%)
EEG sampling rate: 500 Samples/second
EEG units: nV 
EEG montage:
Channel 1: Fp1
Channel 2: AF3
Channel 3: F3
Channel 4: xx
Channel 5: xxx
Channel 6: xxx
Channel 7: xxx
Channel 8: xxx

Trigger information:
Code    Description
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   
8   
9   

User notes:
xxx TCP-IP
```

Now I want to use the MNE-Python library to process the signal. I converted the `.easy` file to `.edf` through Enobio8 device NIC software.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is MNE-Python the right library to use or are there other libraries that can deal with these type of files?
2. When I tried to read the EEG file through the use of `mne.io.read_raw_edf` there are a lot of parameters I should include like the montage (refer to the [link](http://martinos.org/mne/dev/generated/mne.io.read_raw_edf.html#mne.io.read_raw_edf) for more info) how can I create these parameters like montage, eog and misc?
3. Do I have to provide all of these parameters?
4. What should the montage file look like?

Answer (score 1):

See below my answers to your individual points:

> Is MNE-Python is the right library to use? or there are other libraries that can deal with these type of files?

1. Given that you have EEG data in EDF format and want to analyze these data, MNE-Python would be a good choice if you want to do the analysis in Python. However judging from the nature of your questions, it might be a bit easier to start analyzing your data with a GUI (graphical user interface) based approach such as in the Matlab based [eeglab](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/downloadtoolbox.php) toolbox. If you don't have Matlab, there is also a standalone version of eeglab (see my link).

> When I tried to read the EEG file through the use of mne.io.read_raw_edf there are a lot of parameters I should include like the montage (refer to the link for more info) how can I create these parameters like montage, eog and misc?

2. See answer to 3. and 4. - regarding EOG and MISC, those are channel types that should be apparent from the way you recorded the data. Electrodes near the eyes could be called EOG. MISC channels could be any channels that do not record EEG but other data.

> Do I have to fill all of these parameters?

3. No, the only input to the function that you *must* give, is the path to your .edf file.

> What should the montage file look like?

4. A montage file in MNE-Python can either be read from a file that you have with your recorded data, or you could create a standard montage (such as in the [10-20 system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10%E2%80%9320_system_(EEG)) using the [`mne.channels.Montage`](https://martinos.org/mne/dev/generated/mne.channels.Montage.html#mne.channels.Montage) Python class.